# Zend Db query to select all IDs

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

How would I write an Zend DB query to select all from the column ID?

So far I have tried:

```
public function getLatestUserID()
    {
        $ids = $this->select()
             ->where('id = ?');
        return $ids;
    }
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want the `id` column,
You failed to call an execute command.

try:

```
//assuming you are using a DbTable model
public function getLatestUserID()
    {
        $ids = $this->fetchAll('id');
        return $ids;
    }
```

I would do it like this, because I use the select() object for everything:

```
public function getLatestUserID()
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        //I'm not sure if $this will work in this contex but you can out the table name
        $select->from(array($this), array('id'));
        $ids = $this->fetchAll($select);
        return $ids;
    }
```

The first two examples should return just the `id` column of the table, now if you actually want to query for a specific `id`:

```
 public function getLatestUserID($id)
        {
            $select = $this->select();
            $select->where('id = ?', $id);
            //fetchAll() would still work here if we wanted multiple rows returned
            //but fetchRow() for one row and fetchRowset() for multiple rows are probably
            //more specific for this purpose.
            $ids = $this->fetchRow($select);
            return $ids;
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly, I had to replace $this with the table name but perfect, exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @RyanMurphy ya, I made an error it should have been `$this->_name` for the table name.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your class containing getLatestUserID does extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract also :

`$ids = $this->select()->where('id = ?');`  can't work because where('id = ?');  expects an id value like `where('id = ?', $id);`

if what you want is the latest inserted row's Id use :

```
$lastInsertId = $this->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
```

(however if you are using an oracle database this will not work and you should use `$lastInsertId = $this->getAdapter()->lastSequenceId('USER_TABLE_SEQUENCE');` )

Comment: remember `lastInsertId` also does not work correctly with Mysql.

Comment: so what can I use to achieve this then if using mysql

Comment: your table's primary key (user's id) must be set to autoincrement for lastInsertId

Comment: just tried `lastinsertid` with my `mysql` table. my last `id` is 2 but it returned 0. also `auto inc` is set to on.

Comment: are you calling it after your insert ? because zend manual states that if your id is set to autoincrement calling lastInsertId should work (on a mysql DB) http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Comment: im not inserting anything into my table. I just want tot get the last user id.

Comment: i meant after inserting your two rows that are in your table

Comment: i manually entered the data into my table with mysql query browser

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10888/discussion-between-ryan-murphy-and-mona-cheikhna)